# OWASP CsrfGuard token missing while submitting multipart formdata

Tags: struts, csrf, owasp

I have implemented OWASP CsrfGuard 3 filter on an existing Struts 1.1 application, its working fine for every request, except the forms which have a file upload field  and enctype="multipart/form-data". The following message is logged on the console "error:required token is missing from the request".

The csrf token was added as a hidden field on the form, and is present when I view the page source in the browser.

The form works fine if I remove the file field from the form and enctype attribute from html:Form tag.

Please let me know how to configure mulipart file upload with CsrfGuard.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that's a known issue (See the CSRF mailing list, April 2011).

Comment: Thanks for the info, after a little searching i found this [link](https://github.com/esheri3/OWASP-CSRFGuard/issues/5)

Comment: Hi @Sunny, I'm having this same issue, that link you mentioned is not found.
Could you tell if you fixed this?